# Asymptotics of a function that decreases as n increases

Tags: asymptotics

A homework assignment asks me to state the complexity in Big-O notation of the function
$$f(n) =  7n – 3n \log n + 100000 $$

I graphed this function and decreases all the way down to zero nearly its entire lifespan. 
Therefore I concluded that the complexity is bounded by a constant and has the complexity $O(1)$.

Is this correct?

Also out of curiosity, what is the Big-Omega of this function is? The best it could ever run is also O(1). 
What about Big-Theta? I'm having trouble getting my head around these.

Comment: a tricky one. did you think about $O(-n\log n)$?

Comment: It does not just decrease to zero, it turns negative.

Comment: Are you talking about time complexity?

Comment: @RanG. negative values is an odd case for Big-O. I don't think it's ever come up... But, carefully check all the definitions, if it's valid, then ok.

Comment: [Related question about $\Theta$ of negative functions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/definition-of-theta-for-negative-functions).

Comment: See also our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use). You have to get your definitions straight! Note also that there is no algorithm anywhere in sight here! Clearly, $f$ can not be the runtime function of any algorithm. Furthermore, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic) regardings using plots in this context.

Comment: @Raphael It can't be the running time of a useful algorithm, but it can be the running time of some algorithm. Take $n=0$.

Comment: @saadtaame In any reasonable computational model, runtime is at least $1$. The given function assumes negative values, so I maintain that it can't be a runtime function (assuming $n$ is to be the input size).

Answer (score 1):

If you use suitable definitions, you'll find that your function is in

- $O(2^n)$,
- $O(n^4)$,
- $o(1)$ and
- $\Omega(-n^2)$,

among many others. It's likely that the question (implicitly) asks for sharper bounds; I'll leave that for you to figure out.